# Given 2 points with known speed direction and location, compute a path composed of (circle) arcs

Tags: c++, geometry, physics

So, I have two points, say A and B, each one has a known (x, y) coordinate and a speed vector in the same coordinate system. I want to write a function to generate a set of arcs (radius and angle) that lead A to status B.

The angle difference is known, since I can get it by subtracting speed unit vector. Say I move a certain distance with (radius=r, angle=theta) then I got into the exact same situation. Does it have a unique solution? I only need one solution, or even an approximation.

[image: An example]

Of course I can solve it by giving a certain circle and a line(radius=infine), but that's not what I want to do. I think there's a library that has a function for this, since it's quite a common approach.

Comment: Check out [biarcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biarc). Your question is exactly "draw a biarc with given end points and tangents", which is always used in *biarc approximation*. Here is [a great article](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/biarc-interpolation/) to read, too.

Comment: Does your problem require speed to remain constant or (if the end and starting speeds are different) is there a linear change in speed during the transition?

Comment: @VirtualMichael No, I only need the path. By speed vector, I actually mean direction vector.

Comment: @stgatilov Thanks! In the most cases it works like a charm! Unless the direction is totally distorted, the path looks ideal to me. And due to its simplicity(any given ratio of the d1/d2 it generates a unique path), it's easy to calculate(circle). Maybe you could post it as answer? I want to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [biarc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biarc) is a smooth curve consisting of two circular arcs. Given two points with tangents, it is almost always possible to construct a biarc passing through them (with correct tangents).

This is a very basic routine in geometric modelling, and it is indispensable for smoothly approximating an arbirtrary curve (bezier, NURBS, etc) with arcs. Approximation with arcs and lines is heavily used in CAM, because modellers use NURBS without a problem, but machine controllers usually understand only lines and arcs. So I strongly suggest reading on this topic.

In particular, here is a [great article on biarcs](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/biarc-interpolation/) on biarcs, I seriously advice reading it. It even contains some working code, and an interactive demo.